# Alternative to getOrDefault for devices below API 24 Android

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I am writing an Android application and I'm using a Java class that uses has a loop as follows:

```
for (Set<I> itemset : candidateList2) {
    supportCountMap.put(itemset, supportCountMap.getOrDefault(itemset,0)+ 1);
}
```

I get the warning Call requires API level 24(current min is 16) on the method:

```
supportCountMap.getOrDefault(itemset,0)+1);
```

Is there any workaround to this method such that it can work on phones with an SDK version lower than 24 e.g Marshmallow(23) and Lollipop(21)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always implement the same logic yourself:

```
for (Set<I> itemset : candidateList2) {
    Integer value = supportCountMap.get(itemset);
    if (value == null) {
        value = 0;
    }
    supportCountMap.put(itemset, value + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works quite well. Just a question, based on the suggestion by @Bubletan above, the method implementation checks if the HashMap contains the key, would this be necessary in the above snippet of code that is, in conjunction with checking if the value is null?

Comment: `get` would return a `null` for a non-existent key. Generally speaking, using `containsKey` is safer, as maps may have `null` values, but in your case, when you just use a map to hold counters, it's redundant.

Answer (score 26):

Kotlin: Simply use the elvis operator :

```
  val value = map[key] ?: 0
```

if `map[key]` is null then the value will be 0.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest creating `MapCompat` class, copy `Map.getOrDefault` implementation and pass your `map` as an extra argument:

```
public class MapCompat {

    public static <K, V> V getOrDefault(@NonNull Map<K, V> map, K key, V defaultValue) {
        V v;
        return (((v = map.get(key)) != null) || map.containsKey(key))
                ? v
                : defaultValue;
    }
}
```

This pattern is broadly used in [Android support libraries](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support), e.g. [`ContextCompat.getColor`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/compat/java/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.java#L407) is good example